# Print filled PDF form with lpr

Tags: printing, pdf

I'm having trouble printing a filled PDF form using `lpr`. Each time I print using `lpr`, the unfilled original form is printed. Does anyone know how to print the filled content from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try an answer as i faced same issue...
My workaround was to re-compress the saved pdf with `ghostscript` and it became fully printable by gnome viewer and/or LPR
`ghostscript` is already installed in Ubuntu desktop

I re-compressed the pdf file with the `shrinkpdf.sh` script available here:
http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/

Usage:

```
# recompress with 400dpi resolution, save to a new file
./shrinkpdf.sh infile.pdf outfile.pdf 400
```

You can use this script out-of-the-box or you can get inspiration from the shrink function to write your own command fitting to your use.